# Why am I getting this error: undefined method `[]' for 0..5:Range (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, nomethoderror

I'm creating a state machine simplifier in Ruby.  While looping through the table that I create to simplify the state machine, it runs through correctly and produces the desired output, however, I get the following error: :

```
undefined method `[]' for 0..5:Range (NoMethodError)
    from C:/Users/Sara/workspace/StateMachineSimplifier/statemachine_simplifier.rb:64:in each
    from C:/Users/Sara/workspace/StateMachineSimplifier/statemachine_simplifier.rb:64:in x_out
    from C:/Users/Sara/workspace/StateMachineSimplifier/statemachine_simplifier.rb:268:in main
    from C:/Users/Sara/workspace/StateMachineSimplifier/statemachine_simplifier.rb:274:in <main>
```

I know that the error is caused by my while loop that calls the function.  How can I call the function only enough times to end up with the finalized table?

```
=begin 
File: statemachine_simplifier.rb 
Author: Sara Tibbetts 
Date: 04/24/2015 
Description: This program takes in .txt file with a state table 
and reduces it to its simplest form 
=end 

def dup_remove(table0)
  #Simplifies states with same output and next states 
  for i in 0..((table0.size)-1) 
    check1 = table0[i][1]
    check2 = table0[i][2]
    for j in 0..((table0.size)-1)
      if i != j then 
        #States are exactly the same 
        if (table0[i][1] == table0[j][1]) and (table0[i][2] == table0[j][2]) then 
          #Replaces all instances of state to be removed with equivalent state 
          to_rep = table0[i][0] 
          to_rem = table0[j][0]

          t_index = []
          #Removes the state from the array 
          table0[j] = "-1"
          for i in 0..((table0.size)-1)
            for j in 0..((table0[0].size)-1)
              if table0[i][j] == to_rem then 
                table0[i][j] = to_rep 
              end 
            end 
          end 
        end 
      end 
    end
  end

  #Removes the placeholders from the table 
  for i in 0..((table0.size)-1)
    if table0[i] == "-1" then 
      t_index.push(i) 
    end
  end

  if t_index != nil then 
    for i in 0..((t_index.size)-1)
      table0.delete_at(t_index[i])
      for j in i..((t_index.size)-1)
        t_index[j] = t_index[j]-1
      end 
    end 
  end 


  #puts table0.inspect 
  return table0
end 

#loops through the given array, and minimizes the states 
def x_out(arr1, s_table)
  #puts arr1.inspect
  #puts arr1.size
  for i in 0..((arr1.size)-1)
    #Loops through each row of the columns 
    #puts i
    #puts arr1.inspect
    #puts arr1[i].inspect
    for j in 0..((arr1[i].size)-1)
      #If the cell is not an "X"
      if arr1[i][j].size != 1
        #If the states are not equal 
        if arr1[i][j][0] != arr1[i][j][2]                                       ###################1
          #If the first state is less than the second state
          if arr1[i][j][0] < arr1[i][j][2]                                      ###################2
            #If arr1[small-1][(big-2)-(small-1)] = "X"
            if arr1[(arr1[i][j][0])-1][(arr1[i][j][2]-2)-(arr1[i][j][0]-1)] == "X"        ###################3   
              arr1[i][j] = "X" 
            end                                                                 ###################3
            #If the first state is more than the second state 
          else                                                                  ###################2
            #If arr1[small-1][(big-2)-(small-1)] = "X"
            if arr1[arr1[i][j][2]-1][(arr1[i][j][0]-2)-(arr1[i][j][2]-1)] == "X"          ###################4  
              arr1[i][j] = "X"
            end                                                                 ###################4
          end                                                                   ###################2
        end                                                                     ###################1
        if arr1[i][j].size != 1
        #print "Loop 2", arr1.inspect, "\n"
          #If the states are not equal 
          if arr1[i][j][1] != arr1[i][j][3]
            #If the first state is less than the second state
            if arr1[i][j][1] < arr1[i][j][3]
              #puts arr1[i][j].inspect
              #puts arr1[(arr1[i][j][1])-1][(arr1[i][j][3]-2)-(arr1[i][j][1]-1)].inspect
              #If arr1[small-1][(big-2)-(small-1)] = "X"
              if arr1[(arr1[i][j][1])-1][(arr1[i][j][3]-2)-(arr1[i][j][1]-1)] == "X"                         
                arr1[i][j] = "X" 
              end 
              #If the first state is more than the second state 
            else 
              #If arr1[small-1][(big-2)-(small-1)] = "X"
              if arr1[arr1[i][j][3]-1][(arr1[i][j][1]-2)-(arr1[i][j][3]-1)] == "X"             
                arr1[i][j] = "X"
              end 
            end 
          end 
        end
      end 
    end 
  end 
end 

def main()
  #Reads in the .txt file 
  print("Enter a file: ")
  filename = gets.chomp



  #Creates array to store information from file 
  s_table = ""
  i = 0 
  j = 0 


  f = File.open(filename,"r")
    puts "\nState table input: \n"
  f.each_line do |line|
    puts line
    s_table = s_table + line 
  end

  s_table = s_table.split("\n")
  s_table = s_table.map { |data| data.split(' ') }

  #Groups states based on outputs 
  table1 = []
  table0 = []

  for i in 0..((s_table.size)-1)
    if s_table[i][3] == "1" then 
      table1.push(s_table[i])
    elsif s_table[i][3] == "0" then 
      table0.push(s_table[i])
    end
  end

  while dup_remove(table0) != table0
    table0 = dup_remove(table0)
  end

  while dup_remove(table1) != table1 
    table1 = dup_remove(table1)
  end


  #Removes the rest of the unnecessary states 

  #table of states that have the possibility of being combined 
  pos_comb = []

  #Need to make table reflecting staircase [ [AB, AC, AD, AE, AF, AG], [BC, BD, BE, BF, BG], [CD, CE, CF, CG], [DE, DF, DG], [EF, EG], [FG] ]
  for i in 0..((s_table.size)-2)
    # 0 :6, 1: 5, 2:4 . . . 
    #(s_table.size)-(i+1)
    pos_comb[i] = Array.new(s_table.size-(i+1), "0")
  end 

  #puts pos_comb.inspect

  #Creates an array with a numerical equivalent of the state number 
  s0_arr = Array.new(table0.size)
  for i in 0..((s0_arr.size)-1)
    if (table0[i][0].ord >= 30) && (table0[i][0].ord <= 57)  
      s0_arr[i] = table0[i][0] 
    elsif (table0[i][0].ord >= 65) && (table0[i][0].ord <= 90)  
      s0_arr[i] = table0[i][0].ord - 64
    else 
      s0_arr[i] = table0[i][0].ord - 96
    end 
  end 


  s1_arr = Array.new(table1.size)
  for i in 0..((s1_arr.size)-1)
    if (table1[i][0].ord >= 30) && (table1[i][0].ord <= 57)  
      s1_arr[i] = table1[i][0] 
    elsif (table1[i][0].ord >= 65) && (table1[i][0].ord <= 90)  
      s1_arr[i] = table1[i][0].ord - 64
    else 
      s1_arr[i] = table1[i][0].ord - 96
    end 
  end 

  #Loops through all of the items in the s1_arr and s0_arr and places 
  # an "X" on their combined position in the pos_comb array 
  for i in 0..((s0_arr.size)-1)
    for j in 0..((s1_arr.size)-1)
      if s0_arr[i] < s1_arr[j] then 
        #puts (s1_arr[j]-s0_arr[i]-1)
        pos_comb[s0_arr[i]-1][(s1_arr[j]-s0_arr[i])-1] = "X"
      else 
        pos_comb[s1_arr[j]-1][(s0_arr[i]-s1_arr[j])-1] = "X"
      end 
    end 
  end 

#  #reverses the items in the pos_comb arrays 
#  for i in 0..((pos_comb.size)-1)
#    pos_comb[i].reverse
#  end 

  #puts pos_comb.inspect
  #puts pos_comb[0][5]

  #Need to go through the pos_comb array, and wherever there is not an X, fill the 
  #next states of the combination 

  #Loops through the pos_comb array, and wherever there is not an X, places an array of 
  #to hold the next states of the combination 
  for i in 0..((pos_comb.size)-1) 
    for j in 0..((pos_comb[i].size)-1)
      if pos_comb[i][j] != "X"
        pos_comb[i][j] = Array.new(4, 0)

        #Places numerical form of state transitions into new array 

        #Columns 
        for k in 0 .. 1
          #numbers 
          if (s_table[i][k+1].ord >= 30) && (s_table[i][k+1].ord <= 57)
            pos_comb[i][j][k] = s_table[i][k-1]
          #uppercase
          elsif (s_table[i][k+1].ord >= 65) && (s_table[i][k+1].ord <= 90)
            pos_comb[i][j][k] = s_table[i][k+1].ord - 64
          #lowercase
          else 
            pos_comb[i][j][k] = s_table[i][k+1].ord - 96
          end 
        end 

        #Rows 
        for k in 2 .. 3
          #numbers 
          #puts s_table[j].inspect
          if (s_table[(i+j)+1][k-1].ord >= 30) && (s_table[(i+j)+1][k-1].ord <= 57)
            pos_comb[i][j][k] = s_table[j+1][k-1]
          #uppercase
          elsif (s_table[(i+j)+1][k-1].ord >= 65) && (s_table[(i+j)+1][k-1].ord <= 90)
            pos_comb[i][j][k] = s_table[(i+j)+1][k-1].ord - 64
          #lowercase
          else 
            pos_comb[i][j][k] = s_table[(i+j)+1][k-1].ord - 96
          end 
        end 

      end 
    end 
  end 

  puts pos_comb.inspect 
  count = 0

  while x_out(pos_comb, s_table).size == pos_comb.size
    #pos_comb = x_out(pos_comb, s_table)
    pos_comb = x_out(pos_comb, s_table)

  end
  puts "HERE!"
  puts pos_comb.inspect
end

main()
```

My text document looks like the following

```
A B C 1
B D F 1
C F E 0
D B G 1
E F C 0
F E D 0
G F G 0
```

I know that the problem lies in the calling of the function, but I'm not sure how to call it the right amount of times to get the output of the properly minimized state table.

Comment: You're not showing the correct code. The problem appears to be an `each` statement on line 64 in `C:/Users/Sara/workspace/StateMachineSimplifier/statemachine_simplifier.rb`

Comment: Line 64 is   for i in 0..((arr1.size)-1)
I don't have any each statements in the code, I'm using eclipse, and that's how it seems to error on for loops.

Comment: That's really strange. I can recreate the error using `(0..5)[1]`, but don't see anything like that. Can you try running from the command-line, or restarting eclipse. I'm not too familiar with Ruby + Eclipse dev, but know of issues requiring restarts with Java + Eclipse in the past.

Comment: That actually helped.  I've determined that it's changing my array (arr1) to 0..5 at the end, which is causing the issues.  Now, to determine why. . .

Comment: Are you sure line 64 isn't at `for j in 0..((arr1[i].size)-1)`? Then it would make sense since there is an index `[]` operator used.

Comment: As @MartinKonecny mentioned. You are not showing the correct code. Can you paste the entire code required to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I've determined that the problem is how I'm calling the function.  I've added that to the post.

Comment: Whats `pos_comb` and `s_table`? Always make sure that you make it as easy for the other person to have it run by just a copy/paste. It will increase the likelihood of your question being answered.

Comment: You might want to edit the code to make it more Ruby than normal for loops in other languages. try using `.each` to make your code cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
pos_comb = x_out(pos_comb, s_table)
```

`xout` returns the value of the outer `for loop` which is a `range`. In ruby a for loop is an expression. For example:

```
x = for i in (0..5) do puts i end # x is equal to (0..5)
```

which is the same as

```
def x_out()
    for i in (0..5) do puts i end
end

x = x_out()  # x is equal to (0..5)
```

After you return from `x_out` you are overwriting the value of `pos_comb` with the range `0..5`. Then you pass it back into `x_out` which causes your problem on the second iteration of your `while` loop.

Right now it seems that you want to return `arr1` from inside your`x_out` function, so try putting

```
  ...
  end
  arr1  # <- insert this at the last line in your function
end
```

at the end of your function to return `arr1` instead.